# Why are templates specified in the routes rather than inside the controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

It seems to me that the correct approach would bet to state templateUrl in the controller file rather than the routes file. In what situation would one use the same controller with a different template? And how do you do if you want an app without routes, but with templates in different files for each controller?

Comment: I'm not understanding what your question is.  Perhaps if you share some code as to what you're doing; it may provide more context as to why you think it is the wrong approach.  I think the answer to your second question is to use ng-include.

Answer (score 2):

There may be cases where you want to re-use the same controller but bind it to different views based on the route being accessed. Think about a case where you can re-use your controller and have different views for `yoursite.com` and `yoursite.com/mobile`.

Answer (score 1):

> In what situation would one use the same controller with a different
>   template?

I think that @Justin nailed it with the suggestion of different views for a computer-based web site and a mobile-based web site; while using the same controller functionality.

I can't think of a better example.

> How do you do if you want an app without routes, but with templates in
>   different files for each controller?

You can use ng-include and ng-controller to assign a controller to a template without the use of routes.  Sort of like this:

```
<div>
 <div ng-include="'SomeTemplate.html'" ng-controller="SomeCtrl" ></div>
 <div ng-include="'SomeOtherTemplate.html'" ng-controller="SomeOtherCtrl" ></div>
</div>
```